# Reference for definition of residue of a differential form, in all characteristics

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

What is the standard reference for a definition , valid in all characteristics, of the residue in a point of a rational differential form on a curve?

Answer (score 3):

This is done for instance in Serre's *Algebraic Groups and Class Fields*, ch. II, §11. As Serre himself observes, the proof is somewhat artificial; a more elegant one is given in Tate's *Residues of differentials on curves*, Ann. Sci. E.N.S. 1 (1968), 149-159.